# Encoding function for ISO 9796-2

Tags: signature, encoding, rabin-cryptosystem

I try to reproduce the analysis conducted in [this presentation](http://2014.hackitoergosum.org/slides/day3_A_common_weakness_in_RSA_signatures:extracting_public_keys_from_communications_and_embedded_devices_Renaud_Lifchitz_hes2014.pdf) by R. Lifchitz.
Namely, data signed by an 1024-bit key $n$ (Rabin scheme) and following ISO/IEC 9796-2.
From what I understand, for a message $m$ that went through an encoding function $\mu$, the signature $s$ is produced as $s=(\mu(m))^d \pmod{n}$, or maybe using a hash function $h$:  $s=(h(\mu(m)))^d \pmod{n}$.

Assume that we know the public key $n$ (given in the presentation):

```
n = 0xAB9953CBFCCD9375B6C028ADBAB7584BED15B9CA037FADED9765996F9EA1AB983F3041C90DA3A198804FF90D5D872A96A4988F91F2243B821E01C5021E3ED4E1BA83B7CFECAB0E766D8563164DE0B2412AE4E6EA63804DF5C19C7AA78DC14F608294D732D7C8C67A88C6F84C0F2E3FAFAE34084349E11AB5953AC68729D07715
```

The signature taken as example in the presentation is as follows:

```
s = 0x01ccc173930a67cfa5623f4921c1eb63116a658c2604d90a5567e5a3db2ec2bd0041c22898f912f70c4ce91f173b735472183d4314eb1ff543f603800f371a40e891b94e452639c5975bc6a47028e57e34e143a9fec48b92354616c5ed5453d2fea03f2301de468ab465b919fc79b8da94df3e8828c96ed5e5b973fd88e4fd2f
```

Verifying it with $w=s^e \pmod{n}$ yields $v=2(n-w)$ since $w=7\pmod{n}$. The value for $v$ shown in hexadecimal below is highly structured.

```
 00000000: dc 00 13 09 00 71 dc 01 c4 0c 72 29 d2 09 fc e1  .....q....r)....
 00000010: c6 03 ca 05 dc 01 dc 01 de 0f 77 54 a8 4a ef 99  ..........wT.J..
 00000020: ce 18 ef 99 dc 01 dc 01 dc 01 dc 01 dc 01 dc 01  ................
 00000030: dc 01 dc 00 13 09 00 71 dc 01 c4 0c 72 29 d2 09  .......q....r)..
 00000040: fc e1 c6 03 ca 05 dc 01 dc 01 de 0f 77 54 aa 4a  ............wT.J
 00000050: ef 99 ce 18 ef 99 dc 01 dc 01 dc 01 dc 01 dc 01  ................
 00000060: dc 01 dc 01 dc 00 13 09 00 71 dc 01 c4 0c 72 29  .........q....r)
 00000070: d2 09 fc e1 c6 03 ca 05 dc 01 dc 01 de 0f 77 4c  ..............wL
```

From this, and seeing the data actually signed given in the presentation (Slide #30), I cannot figure out the encoding function (there does not seem to have a hash function $h$). I have read in https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/203.pdf that that ISO standard should used `0x6A` header and `0xBC` trailer values, but I cannot find them here. (I add that for a second signature using the same public key, I have the same structured $v$.)

Is there a public description of the encoding function that was used here? A public code implementing the signing algorithm?
Any other indication would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @fgrieu. Indeed, I did $n-J^*$ instead of $2(n-J^*)$, thanks for the correction. I have edited my question to change this.

Comment: I apologize that my earlier comment has mislead you. That was unintentional: I gave indications that do apply to the standard in the question's title, but the signature is per a different standard, as proved by the fact that the rightmost byte you now get for v is neither 6c nor cc. I had not noticed that for lack of time to read the link in the question. Because that's about a deployed system, I won't help you more, as a matter of policy. For the record: I have not participated to the design of this system.

Comment: This is not the padding I get when I decrypt a Bouncy Castle / Java generated signature, so the mystery is not solved by that. However, I hope you do know that ISO/IEC 9796-2 is about *signatures giving message recovery*, so you'd expect part of the data to be included in the signature, and of course most data is "highly structured".

Comment: Yes, I know that some part of the message should be there, that is why I try to parse the result.